# Implementing Precision & Recall using LIBSVM in Java

Tags: java, libsvm, precision-recall

I developed a datamining application using libsvm.jar (independently from weka).
But I can't find how to implement Precision/Recall (in java) to validate my model performance.

Are there any API's to include or methods to use in Libsvm Classes ?

Knowing that such capability is included in C and Python versions of LIBSVM (but not in java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this we require  weka.

Weka and libsvm are available in one package

follow this link for combining Weka and libsvm
http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~yasser/wlsvm/

weka is good calculating  ROC,recall,etc.... 
and libsvm is good for classification, regression,etc...